# Strange fb sdk behavior

Tags: facebook, sdk, behavior, facebook-sdk-3.1

On the PHP script I placed Facebook login button with FB SDK. Several days ago, I found that sometime login display is shifted down, and links on the page are not clickable. Very strange, it is not always but sometime appears in all browsers.

How to fix this problem?